# Drag and drop bounding box offset math

Tags: math, canvas, drag, offset

[image]

I'm creating my own drag and drop using canvas. In order to select the ball, I've created an invisible bounding box around it. Clicking in this area will allow you to drag the ball.

On mouse move, I'm using

```
xBall = xMouse;
yBall = yMouse;
```

So the ball will follow the mouse. This is great except at the very start of the drag, the center of the ball will jump to where the mouse is which I don't want. So I need to take into account the offset between the Mouse and Ball.

Can anyone explain the maths behind this? From my reasoning, I need to add the offset on to the mouse's position. So I get `xBall = xMouse + (xBall - xMouse)` but as you can see, this just ends up giving me `xBall = xBall` which is no use.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I appreciate your hard-coding for this task, but there is no need to reinvent the wheel, try using the Kinetic.js, you will surely praise how efficiently kinetic will handle such tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine where the initial click occured and the offset calculation should be carried out with respect to this initial coordinates.

On mouse down, store the initial clicked coordinates:

```
xInitial = xMouse;
yInitial = yMouse;
movingFlag = true;
```

On mouse move:

```
if (movingFlag) {
    xBall = xBall + xMouse - xInitial;
    yBall = yBall + yMouse - yInitial;
}
```

On mouse up :

```
movingFlag = false;
```

Comment: Yep that's great thanks - just to make things super clear, `xBall = xBallInitial + xMouse - xInitial` and `yBall = yBallInitial + yMouse - yInitial`